# Does AWS DynamoDB API pose a limit to number of records returned in a secondary index query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm woking with DynamoDB using java SDK. The case here is, that I've a secondary index which when queried might contain 1000+ records in the returned result. I'm not sure if DynamoDB returns the result in a paginated form or all records at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamodb paginates the results

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Query and Scan operations. With
>   pagination, Query and Scan results are divided into distinct pieces;
>   an application can process the first page of results, then the second
>   page, and so on. The data returned from a Query or Scan operation is
>   limited to 1 MB; this means that if the result set exceeds 1 MB of
>   data, you'll need to perform another Query or Scan operation to
>   retrieve the next 1 MB of data.
>
> If you query or scan for specific attributes that match values that
>   amount to more than 1 MB of data, you'll need to perform another Query
>   or Scan request for the next 1 MB of data. To do this, take the
>   LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request, and use that value
>   as the ExclusiveStartKey in the next request. This approach will let
>   you progressively query or scan for new data in 1 MB increments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DynamoDB paginates the results. From the [AWS DynamoDB Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Pagination):

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Query and Scan operations. With pagination, Query and Scan results are divided into distinct pieces; an application can process the first page of results, then the second page, and so on. The data returned from a Query or Scan operation is limited to 1 MB; this means that if the result set exceeds 1 MB of data, you'll need to perform another Query or Scan operation to retrieve the next 1 MB of data.